# How to save customer cards using razorpay api, so that I can fetch the saved cards

Tags: razorpay

How can I save customer card details on my web app using razorpay payment gateway integration.
So that I can show the list of cards to user and select a given card to make the payment or recharge the wallet. First of all do we have an API to save the cards using razorpay payment gateway integration. I searched on net and finding the details of adding cards on checkout page which is not going to help me. Please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the RBI guidelines, we save the cards in a tokenised form; Razorpay does not save sensitive card details, we only save the tokens.

It's not available our of the box with Standard checkout

- This is an on-demand feature. Please raise a request with our Support team to get this feature activated on your Razorpay account.
- It takes approximately 5-7 working days to enable tokenisation for Visa, MasterCard and other networks.
- Watch this video to know how to raise a feature enablement request on the Razorpay Dashboard - https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/cards/features/saved-cards/

Comment: Update: Based on my recent discussion with Razorpay, this feature might at cost of 4 lakh INR rupee as on September 2023.